# How to customize SwiftUI's Menu Buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

iMessage has this [Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN4lW.jpg) if you tap on the More Button.

How to make something similar in SwiftUI? I tried using ControlGroups and Custom ControlGroup style but I just can't make it work properly. Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried this:

```
struct CustomControlGroupStyle: ControlGroupStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack { configuration.content } 
        Divider()
    }
}

ControlGroup {
    Button {

    } label: {
        HStack {
            Image("ProfileImage")
            Text("Name")
        }
    }
}.controlGroupStyle(CustomControlGroupStyle())
```

Which results in:

[image: Demo]

I need to achieve something like this:
[image: Menu]

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple has access to a lot of cool things they haven't opened up for devs. I think maybe one day this will come, in the meantime I would [file FB](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) so that they know devs want it!